# Jquery get id of an element on click of a common class

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I am programmatically populating options to increase and decrease the value of an element and store the same in the DB table. To get a better idea, consider the following example:

```
<tr>
  <td id="name_1">Element 1</td>
  <td><a href="#" class="increase" id="inc_1">increase icon</a></td>
  <td><a href="#" class="decrease" id="dec_1">decrease icon</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td id="name_2">Element 2</td>
  <td><a href="#" class="increase" id="inc_2">increase icon</a></td>
  <td><a href="#" class="decrease" id="dec_2">decrease icon</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td id="name_n">Element n</td>
  <td><a href="#" class="increase" id="inc_n">increase icon</a></td>
  <td><a href="#" class="decrease" id="dec_n">decrease icon</a></td>
</tr>
```

Whenever I click any among the `n` increase / decrease icon, I need to access the value of `#name_n`. For which, I wrote the following function:

```
$(".increase").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id'); //get the id of the element that was clicked.
  console.log(id);

  var arr = id.split("_"); //split to get the number
  var no = arr[1]; //get the number

  var name = $("#name_"+no).text(); //get the required value in name_n
  console.log(name); 
 });
//replica for decrease class as well.
```

**Problem :**
Every time I click **any** increase icon, in my `console`, I'm getting `id` as `inc_1` only! So, the value of `name` is `Element 1` always. Same happens with `click` function for `.decrease`.

I have tried with the following ways to get the `id`:

```
var id = this.id;
var id = $(this).get(0).id;
var id = $(this)[0].id;
```

But nothing changed. The same problem persists. What's wrong and how do I resolve this?

Comment: `this.id` is correct, Show how you are generating the elements the problem is there. Additionally, why you want to get the `id`? may be we can help clear idea of the problem then we can help better

Comment: @Satpal, Like I have mentioned already, tried using `this.id` as well, nothing changed.

Comment: Again asking same question __Show how you are generating the elements the problem is there.__

Comment: make sure (inspecting the html) that ids are correct once generated. Add a jsfiddle so we can help you.

Comment: I'm generating them in `Laravel` using `blade` syntax, my `view-source-code` actually displays elements with the `id` as expected.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. Try to reproduce this problem at http://jsfiddle.net. I would also recommend another approach using data attributes.

Comment: @Dacklf `id`s are being generated as expected. Since I'm generating the elements using `Laravel - blade` syntax, I guess `jsfiddle` wouldn't be meaningful.

Comment: here's the jsFiddle. Your code works. It's not the better approach but it works. https://jsfiddle.net/fwnnvasr/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct at first glance. Maybe there is some issue with rendering, perhaps the elements really get the same ID.

However, I would recommend a different approach for this task, without using ID's. You can achieve your goal by referencing the `TD` element relatively to the clicked increase/decrease button. I mean something like this.

```
$(".increase").click(function(){
  var $td = $(this).closest("tr").children(":eq(0)"); //get the TR's first TD

  var name = $td.text(); //get the required value in name_n td
  console.log(name); 
 });
```

Comment: This does work. Thank you for your time. I am not accepting the answer because I would like to know the reason behind this bug/error. If I don't find that in a few days, I will accept your answer and give you the credit for helping out. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a more generic class on the elements you wish tou target after the click(currently #name_n) and use the [.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [.siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) methods.

html

```
<tr>
  <td id="name_n" class="target">Element n</td>
  <td><a href="#" class="increase" id="inc_n">increase icon</a></td>
  <td><a href="#" class="decrease" id="dec_n">decrease icon</a></td>
</tr>
```

js

```
$(".increase").click(function(){
    var name = $(this).closest('td').siblings('.target').text();
    console.log(name);
});
```

Here is a working demo https://jsfiddle.net/0hru2jtx/